# Measuring reliability on newer harddrives in usb 3 enclosures

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage, drive-enclosure, reliability

I used to measure the reliability of my hard drives via S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology), even for my external hard drives in USB enclosures.

My newer hard drives that I directly buy in USB 3 enclosures (e.g. https://www.intenso.de/en/products/hard-drives/memory-case) don't seem to offer S.M.A.R.T. any more.

**How can I measure the reliability of newer hard drives?**

- Measure the reliability not via S.M.A.R.T. but some other method? Is there a hard drive testing tool that checks writes and reads, similar to memory testing tools?
- Switch the USB enclosure? I heard that sometimes the enclosure and not the hard drive forbids getting the S.M.A.R.T. features
- If not, is there a list of which hard drives and USB enclosures support S.M.A.R.T., so I can buy only those in the future?

Comment: Note: in most cases, trimming does not work over usb 3!!! So do not use SSD.

Comment: Wow, that is some important information. So no trimming (which improves the performance of writing data to SSDs and contributes to longer SSD life) when you use an SSD in an USB 3 enclosure!?

Comment: I had some broken laptops what I have thrown out. But I kept their SSD disks, and later I wanted to use them for some home archive purposes (to have a many-copy archive of old family photos). Actually, archive is not a very often happening writing function but to be unable to trim, that made me crazy. I investigated it deeply and now I know what I know.

Comment: Can you force the enclosure to use USB 2 and thus enable trimming?

Comment: No, no. Very rarely, it can happen with usb3 (with new usb controller ( == new laptop) AND a new ssd). It can not ever happen with usb 1/2. There are promises that it will work with usb 4 - but I do not believe them until I did see it with my own eyes.

Comment: The cause is this: SSD over USB can work on two methods. 1) there is a "block device access over usb" protocol, this what also the pen drives are doing. It has absolutely no trim/unmap command. 2) there is a "block device over scsi over usb" protocol. SCSI HAS trim/unmap, but to enable it, you need support by *both* of your USB controller and by your SATA/USB adapter.

Comment: If any of them does not support the feature, they silently fallback to (1), *without saying anything to you*. If your SATA/USB adapter is old, you can buy a better one (ideally whose documentation explicitly says that it has trim/unmap). But in most cases, you have no way to replace your usb controller, at least not in a common laptop setting.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly every enclosure now has a converter board speaking USB on one side and SATA, SATA M2, or NVME M.2 on the other. Most I've seen lately don't pass S.M.A.R.T because that extra logic to translate cost additional to manufactor and develop.

If performance and reliability are important, go with one that advertises trim support. Such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MNFH1PX)

If you need enclosures for Spinning Disks (HDD), Smartmontools has [some support](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/USB) for them. I've had varying degrees of luck in the past. Including buying the same one to learn it now isn't reliable.

Comment: Most of my external hard drives (esp. those I buy directly in an USB enclosure) are not SSDs but (spinning) hard disks. Does the first part of your answer apply to USB enclosures for hard disks, too? If so, do you also have a link to a hard disk USB enclosure that supports S.M.A.R.T.?

Comment: I updated with a link to smartmontools, it's unfortunately a bit of trial an error to find ones that actually work well (even if technically supported.)